# Why UISearchBar not invoke UISearchBarDelegate when UIAlertView add a UISearchBar?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have already set UISearchBar's delegate but why does it not invoke `UISearchBarDelegate` while operation hospitalSearchBar.

---

TestViewController.h

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>

- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

TestViewController.m

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation TestViewController

- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
        UISearchBar *hospitalSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
        [hospitalSearchBar setDelegate:self];
        [hospitalSearchBar setShowsSearchResultsButton:YES];
        UIPickerView *hospitalPickerview = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
        MAlertView *alert = [[MAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"提交" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
        [alert addSearchBar:hospitalSearchBar placeHolder:@"Key Word"];
        [alert addPickerView:hospitalPickerView];
        [alert setDelegate:self];
        [alert show];
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{return YES;}

- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{return YES;}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{[self endEditing:YES];}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code given me errors :)

However my view is , you are adding the `UISearchBar` inside a `MAlertView` (**subclass** with **`delegate self`**) .

So implement the delegates inside the `MAlertView` and you can detect the `UISearchBar` delegates in `MAlertView` class.

If it not fixed, please provide me full implementation details of `MAlertView` class.

Comment: - (void)addSearchBar:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar placeHolder:(NSString *)placeHolder{
    if(aSearchBar != nil){
        searchBarCount++;
        aSearchBar.frame = CGRectZero;
        aSearchBar.placeholder = placeHolder;
        [self addSubview:aSearchBar];
    }
}

Comment: - (void)addPickerView:(UIPickerView *)aPickerView{
    if(aPickerView != nil){
        pickerViewCount++;
        aPickerView.frame = CGRectZero;
        [self addSubview:aPickerView];
    }
}

Comment: OverWrite - (void)layoutSubviews;

Comment: #define kMAlertViewMargin 10.0
#define kMAlertViewSearchBarHeight  44.0
#define kMAlertViewPickerViewHeight 216.0

Comment: Because my account does not have enough right, so I can only provide these.   Want more?